# Maven project with many implementations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to build a Maven-Eclipse project, which can handle many implementation.
Its a MVC project. I want a common *controller*, and to have two (or more) *service/dao* implementations.
The *controller* project has lots of interfaces for the other ones (Services, Daos, Entities).

I want something like this:

[image: Desired]

Currently, I have something more like this.

[image]

It "works" and generates working wars when build:package, but i can't make it work on Eclipse. I'm getting the error below when I start the Tomcat 7 (using JDK 7).

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file
    [D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\webapps\Impl1\WEB-INF\classes\spring-database.xml]: 
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ar/com/company/ml/core/entity/Publication
```

Publication is an interface in "Controller" project.

I'm using

- org.eclipse.m2e.maven
- Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT Annotation Processor Toolkit

Thank you and sorry for the images, I think they will be usefull.
Please help me organize this, or provide any good tutorial with this structure.

Controller POM:

```
<parent> 
    <groupId>ar.com.company</groupId> 
    <artifactId>Packer1</artifactId> 
    <version>3.0.0</version> 
</parent> 
<artifactId>ControllerProject</artifactId>
```

Packer1 POM:

```
<groupId>ar.com.company</groupId> 
<artifactId>Packer1</artifactId> 
<version>3.0.0</version> 
<packaging>pom</packaging> 
<modules> 
    <module>ControllerProject</module> 
    <module>ServiceImpl1</module> 
</modules>
```